# Plain text password in Spring Security session

Tags: security, grails, spring-security

I am working on a Grails application that uses the excellent Spring Security Plugin. The authentication happens through Oracle Access Manager which protects the application URL. So I just use the PreAuth filter and never had to worry about passwords. Until now.

There is another application that we need to integrate with (that manages freezer Samples and need user access management so that user's don't see someone else's samples) and uses LDAP. The said application exposes an API that takes in a username password and returns data based that user's access (there is no on behalf of user feature).

***The problem is*** that I need to ask users for their passwords and send plain text password to that service. So hashing and encoding needs to be reversible and I cannot just compare hashcodes. Any suggestions on how to manage this in the best way possible?

I was thinking of using a random salt created on server (and cycle that like every 6 hours), encode the password and set it in a short life cookie, and decode it on the server when making the call to the external service. This way a potential attacker will need data from server memory and the cookies from user's system and I don't store plain text password anywhere. Just a naive attempt. Very open to suggestions.

Comment: "The problem is that I need to ask users for their passwords and send plain text password to that service.". -- **This** is exactly the problem. If at some point you need plain text passwords, solve that rather than obfuscating the problem.

Comment: @Krease, not sure if you are annoyed at the presentation. I used bold characters to let users get to my question if they didn't want to read the background. I am not sure what you mean. I cannot solve the external APIs requiring a password if that's what you mean. Need suggestions to best manage that. And how have I obfuscated the problem?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. No annoyance or understanding issues here. You're looking for a solution that does not change the API. I think this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. The real problem is the requirement to decrypt to plain-text passwords - Ideally you'd be able to push back on that requirement.  I recognize this may not be possible, which is why I put it as a comment instead of an answer.  My statement about "obfuscating the problem" was response to the salts/encodings/etc to hide the plain-text issue

Answer (score 0):

So I hacked one of my apps to work like this:

In the User class: (Spring Security User.groovy)

```
static transients = ['springSecurityService', 'rawPassword']

//To bypass facebook users who log in via facebook
//we will back up original hashed password string
//log them in then save old password has by calling user.rawPassword=oldHash
//this will update underlying password with string hash value
void setRawPassword(String p) {
    password=p
}
```

Then in the relevant service

```
//Get old password hash
def oldPassword=user?.password
        String authPassword
        if (oldPassword) {
            def uid = user.password + new UID().toString() + prng.nextLong() + System.currentTimeMillis()
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest(uid.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            def token1 = hash.encodeBase64()
            user.password = token1
            //Generate a random password
            authPassword = token1
            //Update user Password to be random Password
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken uat1 = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.username, authPassword, null)
            uat1.setDetails(user)
            SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            //Re-setAuthentication of springSecurity using new Password
            context.setAuthentication(uat1)
            if (oldPassword) {
                //Now we are authenticated let's set back the original Hash as the hash we collected in oldPassword 
                //just before doing the hack
                user.rawPassword = oldPassword
                user.save(flush: true)
            }
            springSecurityService.reauthenticate user.username
        }
```

This is rather an ugly hack to authenticate as a user without changing their set password (in the end) during process changed and changed back again..

I am not recommending it but it may be an easier option than what you have outlined